# How to Use CURDATE() in FPDF

Tags: mysql, fpdf

I want to put the current date in `FPDF Cell`.

I used the following query but I don't know how to put it there.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( CURDATE( ) ,  '%d/%m/%Y' )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the current date, you can use PHP's [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function:

```
$currentDate = date("j/n/Y");
```

If you need to use SQL, you can use this query to achieve the same thing:

```
SELECT CONCAT(DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE), '/',
          MONTH(CURRENT_DATE), '/',
          YEAR(CURRENT_DATE));
```

Note that these do not include leading series. Date will be in the format of `5/6/2015`.